# Node.js => TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'

Tags: node.js, object, orm, save, sequelize.js

I'm new to Node.js and i'm trying to run a sort of insert query. Here is my code:

```
exports.savetea = function(req, res){

var quantity = req.query.quantity;

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('nodehmssm', 'root', 'root', {host: "localhost", port: 3306, dialect: 'mysql'});

var Tea = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/model/tea");

Tea.build({quantity: quantity, status: "active"}).save();

res.send("Tea added...");
};
```

My tea.js file is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define("tea", {
    id : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    quantity : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    status : DataTypes.STRING,
    created_at : DataTypes.DATE
});
};
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the error

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'

Also to mention, the settings are good as I can run the login code **select * from where...**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doing a little reading on sequelize, and I'm thinking it might be because you have undefined properties of `Tea`. Namely you define `id`, and `created_at` in your model, but don't set them when you build since you don't have a `defaultValue`.

Comment: Yes Jason, you are right, id is auto_increment type and I didn't know Node.js handles createdat, updatedat automatically.
The error that 'save()' is undefined is misleading though
Thanks for the quick answer, it saved me lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but perhaps I can help someone that has that problem.

Actualy the problem is that you are calling a `.save()` method of something that doesnt have such a method.

This is a common mistake. You are not using the `.build()` method correctly. See example below.

**What you are doing:**

```
Tea.build({quantity: quantity, status: "active"}).save();
```

**What you should be doing is this:**

```
var actualObject = Tea.build({quantity: quantity, status: "active"});
actualObject.save() //etc...
```

You see an error because `Tea` is actualy an object of the model **NOT** a instace of that model that you just built.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Somewhat Misleading Error Message

In Sequelize, you cannot save an object with undefined properties.

Since your model had no `defaultValue`, and you didn't define `id` or `created_at`, the `.build()` method was not creating a `.save()` method on the object it returned.

For more on the documentation, checkout their documentation on [built instances](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#instances-build) and [this section on how to implement `autoincrement`](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-definition).

Answer (score -1):

The type error you are getting is stating the object Tea has no method called .save. In your code:

```
Tea.build({quantity: quantity, status: "active"}).save();
```

Tea is your object and build is calling an instance method called .save where you want to insert your JSON data. When you call either a class or instance method from a specific sequelize model, you will get the error you found.

I recommend for you to use a template for your sequelize models to help resolve this common mistake. Below is my suggestion:

**modelTemplate.js**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {                                                    
    return sequelize.define('User', {                                                             
        col1: DataTypes.STRING,
        col2: DataTypes.STRING                                                                
    },{                                                                                              
        classMethods: {                                                                              
            doSomething: function(successcb, errcb, request) {}                                             
       },                                                                                           
       instanceMethods: {                                                                           
           saveSomething: function(data) {}                                              
       }                                                                                            
     });                                                                                              
   };
```

For your specific answer. I would adjust your call to the model with the following lines:

```
 var data_json = {quantity: quantity, status: "active"};
 Tea.build().save(data_json);
```

**tea.js**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {                                                    
    return sequelize.define('tea', {                                                             
         id : DataTypes.INTEGER,
         quantity : DataTypes.INTEGER,
         status : DataTypes.STRING                                                                 
    },{                                                                                              
        classMethods: {                                                                              
            doSomething: function(successcb, errcb, request) {}                                             
       },                                                                                           
       instanceMethods: {                                                                           
           save: function(data) {}                                              
               var new_instance = Tea.build({
                    quantity: data[0].quantity,
                    status: data[0].status
            });         
            //saving instance
            // you can also build, save and access the object with chaining:                                                             
            new_instance
            .save()
            .success(function(){}).error("instance error in .save() method"); 
       }                                                                                            
     });                                                                                              
   };
```

Edit: made a correction to a comma in the template.